# What is a good way to modify the upload link in a document library in 2010?

Tags: development, document-library

I have a custom upload form that I want to incorporate with new document libraries. Ideally, user will be able to add document libraries with this updated link to their site on their own without having to use SPD.

What is the best way to modify the document library upload link? I'm open to development if that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the upload and related links, there are 7 locations where links need to be modified:

1) Ribbon - Documents - New Document > Custom Action Hide

2) Ribbon - Documents - Upload Document > Custom Action Replace

3) Ribbon - Manage - View Properties > Custom List Definition (schem.xml) - Form

4) Ribbon - Manage - Edit Properties > Custom List Definition (schem.xml) - Form

5) ECB - View Properties > Custom List Definition (schem.xml) - Form

6) ECB - Edit Properties > Custom List Definition (schem.xml) - Form

7) "Add new item" >

1. Custom List Definition (schem.xml) - View - XslLink
2. XSL - Custom vwstyles.xsl

**Steps 1 & 2:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407619.aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.ReplacementButton"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Title="Replace a Ribbon Button">
        <CommandUIExtension>
          <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <!-- Hide OOTB Upload and New Document Buttons -->
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument" />
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.NewDocument" />
            <!-- APC Upload Button -->
            <CommandUIDefinition
                Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
                <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument.ReplacementButton"
                    Command="ReplacementButtonCommand"
                    Image16by16="/_layouts/apc/img/apclogo16.png"
                    Image32by32="/_layouts/apc/img/apclogo32.png"
                    LabelText="Upload Document"
                    Sequence="1"
                    TemplateAlias="o1" />
          </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
                <CommandUIHandler
                    Command="ReplacementButtonCommand"
                    CommandAction="javascript:alert('This button has been replaced.');" />
            </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

**Steps 3 - 6**

```
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" SetupPath="Layouts\MyView.aspx" Url="MyView.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" SetupPath="Layouts\MyEdit.aspx" Url="MyEdit.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

**Steps 7**

Essentially you'll be updating an XSL file.

Custom List Template > schema.xml > views.view.xsllink > custom_vwstyles.xsl

The blog post below walks you though all of the steps:
http://byteloom.blogspot.com/2012/01/custom-upload-form-for-document-library.html

**Update**

It looks like the upload page property is associated with the SPWeb not the SPList object per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.customuploadpage(v=office.14).aspx?cs-lang=csharp

Comment: The step7 is not answered completely on that post... Can you provide another direction? Thanks Bruno